# Foreach loop error

Tags: c#

I'm gettin an error pointing to `in` in the foreach loop!? Has never happens before. What could be the reason for this? Have I missed something?

Error message:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' 
>       occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

---

> Additional information: Unable to create a constant 
>        value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types 
>        or enumeration types are supported in this context.

My code:

```
List<int> WeeksInProject = new List<int>();
var w = from x in db.Activities 
        where x.ProjectID.Equals(1) 
        select x;

foreach (var wNum in w)
{
    WeeksInProject.Add(wNum.WeekNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int> WeeksInProject = new List<int>();
var w = from x in db.Activities 
        where x.ProjectID != null && (int)x.ProjectID == 1 
        select x;

foreach (var wNum in w)
{
    WeeksInProject.Add(wNum.WeekNumber);
}
```

Since the ProjectID is an `int?` you have to check for nullity and then cast it.

Answer (score 6):

```
var w = from x in db.Activities 
        where x.ProjectID.Equals(1) select x;
```

should be:

```
var w = from x in db.Activities 
        where x.ProjectID == 1 select x;
```

If `ProjectID` is `int?`,

```
var w = from x in db.Activities where 
        x.ProjectID.HasValue &&
        x.ProjectID.Value == 1 select x;
```